# Invalid action configuration Image URI container named: <IMAGE_URI> does not match any of the missing containers in the task definition file provided

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-code-deploy

I got this error on my pipeline,i am trying to test a gree/blue deployment. my task definition looks like this.

```html
    "executionRoleArn": "arn:aws:iam::4634380474765:role/ecsTaskExecutionRole",
    "containerDefinitions": [
      {
        "name": "containername",
        "image": "<IMAGE_NAME>",
        "essential": true,
          
       
        "portMappings": [
          {
            "hostPort": 80,
            "protocol": "tcp",
            "containerPort": 80
          }
        ]
          }
        ],
        "requiresCompatibilities": [
            "FARGATE"
        ],
        "networkMode": "awsvpc",
        "cpu": "256",
        "memory": "512",
        "family": "myTaskDefination"
    }
```

buildspec.yml

```html
version: 0.2

phases:       
  pre_build:
    commands:
      - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR.....
      - aws --version
      - echo $$AWS_DEFAULT_REGION
      - REPOSITORY_URI=account.dkr.ecr.ap-southeast-2.amazonaws.com/tv2testenv
      - aws ecr get-login-password --region $AWS_DEFAULT_REGION | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $REPOSITORY_URI
      - COMMIT_HASH=$(echo $CODEBUILD_RESOLVED_SOURCE_VERSION | cut -c 1-7)
      - IMAGE_TAG=${COMMIT_HASH:=latest}
      

  build:
    commands:
      - echo Build started on `date`
      - echo Building the Docker image...
      - docker build -t $REPOSITORY_URI:latest .
      - docker tag $REPOSITORY_URI:latest $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG

  post_build:
    commands:
      - echo Build completed on `date`
      - echo Pushing the Docker images...
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
      - docker push $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG
      - printf '{"ImageURI":"%s"}' $REPOSITORY_URI:$IMAGE_TAG > imageDetail.json 
      

artifacts:
  files:
    - appspec.yml
    - taskdef.json
    - imageDetail.json
```

appspec.yml

```html
version: 0.0
Resources:
  - TargetService:
      Type: AWS::ECS::Service
      Properties:
        TaskDefinition: <TASK_DEFINITION>
        LoadBalancerInfo:
          ContainerName: "Containername"
          ContainerPort: 80
```

pipeline.json

```html
   {
                "name": "Deploy",
                "actions": [
                    {
                        "name": "Deploy",
                        "actionTypeId": {
                            "category": "Deploy",
                            "owner": "AWS",
                            "provider": "CodeDeployToECS",
                            "version": "1"
                        },
                        "runOrder": 1,
                        "configuration": {
                            "AppSpecTemplateArtifact": "BuildArtifact",
                            "ApplicationName": "odeDeploy",
                            "DeploymentGroupName": "DeploymentGroup",
                            "Image1ArtifactName": "BuildArtifact",
                            "Image1ContainerName": "<IMAGE_URL>",
                            "TaskDefinitionTemplateArtifact": "BuildArtifact"
                        },
                        "outputArtifacts": [],
                        "inputArtifacts": [
                            {
                                "name": "BuildArtifact"
                            }
                        ],
                       
                    }
                ]
            }
```

The error is thrown from part of the pipeline above, complaining about the Image1ContainerName. I cannot seem to figure out what i did wrong. The Image1ContainerName isn't it suppose to be the image url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set your CodePipeline to use `IMAGE_URI` as the Dynamic update task definition.

While your task definition is using:

```
"image": "<IMAGE_NAME>",
```

The simplest solution would be changing the task definition to use

```
"image": "<IMAGE_URI>",
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer proved relevant for me. But also in my case I still saw this error until I fixed the bigger issue:

My `taskdef.json` was not quite formatted correctly — I had `container_definitions` instead of `containerDefinitions`.

I should have followed the instructions closer which would have validated that data directly with ECS, but it's interesting (and completely par for the course with other AWS high-level services) that this CodePipeline action fails in this very non-helpful way. I finally started validating it using this command (and fixed the issues with it):

```bash
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://./taskdef.json
```

That did not solve my issue though. I checked so many times, tried several iterations of different placeholder names and using `< >` or not... nothing made it happy. I was consistently getting the error in the OP, even though I am sure everything was in accordance with the documentation.

Then I found an [example from AWS that actually interpolates the image URI into the `taskdef.json` before ever sending it to the `CodeDeployToECS` action](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-ecs-fullstack-app-terraform/blob/98ee8e693a5ebc4b14f3dfe731bdc786637c1eb4/Infrastructure/Templates/buildspec.yml#L42-L49):

```yaml
# buildspec.yaml
phases:
  pre_build: ...
  build: ...
  post_build:
    commands:
      #...
      - sed -i "s|<REPO_URL>|$REPO_URL|g" taskdef.json
      #...
```

(and in this example's task-definition, `<REPO_URL>` is the equivalent placeholder to `<IMAGE_NAME>` in the OP)

This steps around the issue and works great. In my case, I'm already using CodeBuild to build a docker image and to inject the `appspec.yaml` and `imageDefinition.json` and `taskdef.json` files as artifacts to the `CodeDeployToECS` action, so this is a simple change that just works.

I'm not sure if it was necessary, but I also removed these keys from my `CodeDeployToECS` action configuration, since I'm no longer asking the Action to do the interpolation:

- `Image1ArtifactName`
- `Image1ContainerName`